# STM32WB55 cannot enter STOP mode

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I am trying to put my MCU STM32WB55 into STOP mode to save current but it appears not working for some reason. The code is simple, it basically blinks the LEDs for several seconds then turns them off, then initiates STOP mode. However, when I captured the current it stays the same with or without introducing the STOP function. I am not sure what goes wrong.

Below is the code:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2021 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "stm32wbxx_hal_pwr.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
LPTIM_HandleTypeDef hlptim2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
int ledon = 1;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_LPTIM2_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void HAL_LPTIM_CompareMatchCallback(LPTIM_HandleTypeDef *hlptim);
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_LPTIM2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    HAL_LPTIM_TimeOut_Start_IT(&hlptim2, (30*250), 1000);   //period: 250=1s
    
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
        
        if (ledon != 0)
        {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            
            HAL_Delay(3000);
            
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET);
            
            HAL_Delay(3000);
            
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            
            HAL_Delay(3000);
            
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET);
            
            ledon = 0;
            
            //enter stop mode
            HAL_SuspendTick();
            HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_MAINREGULATOR_ON, PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);
            
            SystemClock_Config();
            HAL_ResumeTick();
        }
        
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSI1
                              |RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = RCC_MSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSIState = RCC_LSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure the SYSCLKSource, HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2 clocks dividers
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK4|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK2
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLK2Divider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLK4Divider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the peripherals clocks
  */
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_SMPS|RCC_PERIPHCLK_LPTIM2;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.Lptim2ClockSelection = RCC_LPTIM2CLKSOURCE_LSI;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.SmpsClockSelection = RCC_SMPSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.SmpsDivSelection = RCC_SMPSCLKDIV_RANGE1;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Smps */

  /* USER CODE END Smps */
}

/**
  * @brief LPTIM2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_LPTIM2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPTIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END LPTIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPTIM2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END LPTIM2_Init 1 */
  hlptim2.Instance = LPTIM2;
  hlptim2.Init.Clock.Source = LPTIM_CLOCKSOURCE_APBCLOCK_LPOSC;
  hlptim2.Init.Clock.Prescaler = LPTIM_PRESCALER_DIV128;
  hlptim2.Init.Trigger.Source = LPTIM_TRIGSOURCE_SOFTWARE;
  hlptim2.Init.OutputPolarity = LPTIM_OUTPUTPOLARITY_HIGH;
  hlptim2.Init.UpdateMode = LPTIM_UPDATE_IMMEDIATE;
  hlptim2.Init.CounterSource = LPTIM_COUNTERSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  hlptim2.Init.Input1Source = LPTIM_INPUT1SOURCE_GPIO;
  hlptim2.Init.Input2Source = LPTIM_INPUT2SOURCE_GPIO;
  if (HAL_LPTIM_Init(&hlptim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPTIM2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END LPTIM2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA1 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PE4 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PB5 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void HAL_LPTIM_CompareMatchCallback(LPTIM_HandleTypeDef *hlptim)
{
    ledon = 1;
}
/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Comment: It looks like you have enabled a periodic timer interrupt on LPTIM2.  Does that timer continue to run and interrupt in low power mode?  If so it could be waking the device up out of low power mode.

Comment: Yes but the timer triggers every 30s, so I should be able to see the low current draw. I did comment out the timer and initiated the STOP mode in the first place to test, but same result, no low current draw

Comment: Do you have a debugger attached to the board? I remember some stm32 refusing to sleep with connected JTAG.

Comment: @Flexz no there is no debugger attached

Comment: We can't see some functions detail but if you sure about your code, there are a few power mode that related LPTIM. According to reference manuel some details about these relationship, such as sleep, stop and standbye mode behaviors when an interrupt occurs or reinit needs for power down. You can search about a bit more, if you don't before.